# Location manager error KCLErrorDomain error 0

Tags: ios

Sometimes I get this error on the device.

I've seen past question on this saying the error will occur if simulation location is enabled in the scheme. However I'm getting this on hardware not the simulator.

Other answer say to check there is Wifi/3G. Which there is.

Other answer say to reset the location services and the network services. However this would imply some terminal fault with the device, but after getting this error I might try again later and it would work.

Answer (score 1):

From [Apple Docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CoreLocationConstantsRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010237-CH2-SW2),

```
typedef enum {
   kCLErrorLocationUnknown  = 0,
   kCLErrorDenied,
   kCLErrorNetwork,
   kCLErrorHeadingFailure,
   kCLErrorRegionMonitoringDenied,
   kCLErrorRegionMonitoringFailure,
   kCLErrorRegionMonitoringSetupDelayed,
   kCLErrorRegionMonitoringResponseDelayed,
   kCLErrorGeocodeFoundNoResult,
   kCLErrorGeocodeFoundPartialResult,
   kCLErrorGeocodeCanceled,
   kCLErrorDeferredFailed,
   kCLErrorDeferredNotUpdatingLocation,
   kCLErrorDeferredAccuracyTooLow,
   kCLErrorDeferredDistanceFiltered,
   kCLErrorDeferredCanceled,
} CLError;
```

`kCLErrorDomain` error comes unexpectedly, reason may be different. You are getting the *error 0*; i.e `kCLErrorLocationUnknown` **the location manager was unable to obtain a location value right now.**

Comment: Thanks, but I want to know why it couldn't get one right now (when its in the same state and location as all the other times when it can get one).

Comment: It may be some internal problem or may be the bug, not sure.